# How to remove video from Vimeo server using api?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to remove video from `Viemo Pro` server using vimeo API in `php`. but the video not remove from vimeo server. `FATAL ERROR`  uncaught exception are throw in php.
I have successfully connected to Vimeo pro API and successfully upload video in Vimeo Pro.

> Below is my php Code

```
 $file_name='https://api.vimeo.com/videos/129529345';
 $uri = $lib->request($file_name,array(),'DELETE');
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($uri);
 die;
```

> Below is the screenshot

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Url is wrong, The url is `/videos/127008336` instead of  `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/127008336`

```
 $file_name='/videos/127008336';
    //  Send this to the API library.
    $uri = $lib->request($file_name,array(),'DELETE');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($uri);
    die;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, the provided hostname is

> api.vimeo.comhttps

This may cause your FATAL ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is showing you are trying to resolve this address api.vimeo.comhttps, which is unresolveable since vimeo.comhttps does not exist.

Comment: i also try to remove https from url but some other error occur

Comment: The protocol https:// should be correct, it just seems that there is a mistake in your variable/string, where 'https' is added to the end of the TLD, in your case: 'https://api.vimeo.comhttps' should be 'https://api.vimeo.com'

Comment: thank you so much i have done it. actually had pass the wrong Url

Comment: I have one another question can you help me ? my question is i have to upload video from admin panel of my domain and the size of the video too large such as more 500 MB what is the best way 1) Jquery 2) Form submit, if you have any link from video upload please share.. thanks